# DB table not being seen by web service

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I am using an `asmx` webservice to input data from input by the user on the website to a table on my database called `Booking`.

I have ensured that the table exists in the schema I am using and I've tested my connection string and it works fine. However every time I run the service It cannot seem to see the table in question and I am given this error by the browser:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Booking'.

After debugging it says the issue resides on line 31

> Line 31:         ws.addBooking(name, email, restaurant, add1, add2,
>   add3, county, tel, info);

This is the entire code relating to that line:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Get info
        String name = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
        String email = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
        String restaurant = TextBox3.Text.ToString();
        String add1 = TextBox4.Text.ToString();
        String add2 = TextBox5.Text.ToString();
        String add3 = TextBox6.Text.ToString();
        String tel = TextBox7.Text.ToString();
        String county = DropDownList1.Text.ToString();
        String info = TextArea1.Text.ToString();

        //Call web service
        Customers ws = new Customers();
        //Pass in parameters
        ws.addBooking(name, email, restaurant, add1, add2, add3, county, tel, info);
    }
```

This is the webmethod `addBooking` that is being called.

```
public void addBooking(String n, String e, String r, String a1, String a2, String a3, String c, String t, String i)
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Booking VALUES(@n, @e, @r, @t, @c, @i, @a1, @a2, @a3)";
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\n00093500\\Desktop\\MMCA2\\APP_DATA\\NORTHWIND.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = n;//name
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@e", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = e;//email
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@r", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = r;//restaurant
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@t", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = t;//telephone
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@c", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = c;//county
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@i", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Value = i;//info
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@a1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = a1;//address
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@a2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = a2;//address
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@a3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = a3;//address
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me decipher what might be causing this issue?

Trying to run this query from withing the `server explorer` in Visual Studio 2010...

```
INSERT INTO Booking(name, email, restaurant, telephone, county, info, add1, add2, add3)
VALUES(John Doe,johndoe@hotmail.com,Johns Restaurant, 1234567,Dublin,Test info,4,Main street,Kinsale)
```

Gets this error

Incorrect Syntax near Doe

Comment: Your connection uses Integrated security, which means that it has different permissions depending on user account. Check that account, that you use to start webservice. It must have same permissions as yours.

Comment: And... string values must be in quotes

Answer (score 1):

Try to write `dbo.Booking` instead of `Booking` in your Insert statement

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Booking VALUES(@n, @e, @r, @t, @c, @i, @a1, @a2, @a3)";
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and still getting the same error at runtime

Comment: and `NORTHWIND.dbo.Booking`?

Comment: Again, no change. I just can't understand what might be the problem!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run the INSERT statement in the correct database.
It might be that the `Initial Catalog` (default database) might differ from the one you want to use.

1. Check the **connection string** to see which database is the default one.
2. Connect to the database using **SQL Server Management Studio** and run a SELECT query against `Booking` to check that you have the required security permissions.
3. Run **SQL Profiler** to see exactly what is going on. This will aid you to debug further.
4. If you are running several database engines on the same machine, verify that you connect to the **correct instance** `MyComputerName\SqlServerInstanceName`.

Comment: Checked `connection String` and it is good, also can run `SELECT` queries on Booking table so it's not a permission issue. However I cannot seem to `INSERT` I keep getting an error which I will post above

Comment: When connecting with SQL Server Management Studio, did you try to do an INSERT-statement as well? Perhaps you only have READ-permissions.

Comment: I should mention David, that I have another method which inserts data to a different table on the same schema and that works as it should with no errors. So I think the READ permission should be valid for the Booking table but I will check just encase.

Comment: @Javacadabra, if you are able to run other INSERT statements using the same connection string, I believe that SQL Profiler is your best friend to debug this problem.